# Find time press and touch coordinates of two simultaneous touchpoints

Tags: android

I have a curious conundrum I am struggling to deal with. I would like the user to use two fingers and touch the screen at the same time with both of them, and I would like to find the touch coordinates and time pressed of each of these touch events.

My first approach when trying to do this was to use the `onTouchListener`, and to set `event.getAction()==(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. However, I soon realized that this method was only good for single touch points, not two simultaneous touch points.

My second approach was to try something like

```
if (event.getAction()==(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || event.getAction()==(MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
    {
    //Find touchtime and touch coordinates
```

but this only recorded the first touch point, not the second touch point. Does anyone know how I would approach this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is close.  First off, two fingers will never go down at the exact same time-  they'll always be off by a few microseconds.  So you don't check if the two come down at the same time, but if they come down with less than a small gap between them (say a few milliseconds).  Secondly, the first finger down generates an ACTION_DOWN.  The second will generate an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN.  The motion event will include the number of pointers down.  So when you see an ACTION_DOWN you save the time, and when you see an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN you check to see if its the second point, and if so you check for the time delta.